# Regarding joomla 1.7 menu module

Tags: joomla1.7

I created a menu module in joomla 1.7, after that when I see the module listing I see that it shows 'published but is pending'.A yello button with an exclaimation sign? I want to make it green ...how do I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set it published with a future start time/date?
Sometimes a server time misconfiguration can cause this.

In the module manager, make sure hat the 'publish up' time has already passed.